# How to open a terminal from within Sublime Text 3

Tags: terminal, sublimetext3

I find many tutorials on how to open sublime text 3 from the terminal via creating a symlink etc. But I'm not really sure on how to open a terminal in the location of the currently opened file from within sublime. I'm using an old macbook with High Sierra if this makes any differnce;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this plugin, [Terminal](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Terminal), it opens a terminal tab on the directory of the currently selected file or project (if you have one open), you can install it through `packagecontrol`, you can configure the key to launch the terminal, and whether you want to use iTerm or the default terminal app.